# How to do a full outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I set the `THEATRES` size using `THEATRES.NUMOFROWS, THEATRES.NUMOFCOLS` and each `SEAT.SEATNO` is tied to `THEATRES.ID` and `SHOWTIMES.ID` is tied to `THEATRES.ID` and `TICKET_ITEMS` are tied to `SHOWTIMES.ID`

I want to display all the values by joining the table using where clause for `showtime.id`. I know outer join will display null on non-matching but my query only shows one records.

```
SELECT 
    SHOWTIMES.ID AS SHOWTIMESID,
    SHOWTIMES.THEATREID,
    THEATRES.THEATRENAME,
    THEATRES.NUMOFROWS,
    THEATRES.NUMOFCOLS,
    SEAT.SEATNO AS SEATLABEL,
    SEAT.ROWID,
    SEAT.COLUMNID,
    TICKET_ITEMS.SEATNO,
    TICKET_ITEMS.TICKETCODE
FROM
    SHOWTIMES FULL OUTER JOIN TICKET_ITEMS ON SHOWTIMES.ID =TICKET_ITEMS.SHOWTIMESID
     FULL OUTER JOIN THEATRES ON SHOWTIMES.THEATREID = THEATRES.ID
     FULL OUTER JOIN SEAT ON SEAT.SEATNO = TICKET_ITEMS.SEATNO
WHERE
    SHOWTIMES.ID = 1
```

;

Comment: Could you please add some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any kind of `OUTER JOIN` and you refer to a column in the `WHERE` you need to handle `NULL`s. If you don't, you turn the `JOIN` into an implicit `INNER JOIN`. Take this simple example:

```
WITH T1 AS(
    SELECT ID, SomeString
    FROM (VALUES(1,'abc'),(2,'def')) V(ID, SomeString)),
T2 AS(
    SELECT ID, fID, AnotherString
    FROM (VALUES(1,1,'asd'),(2,1,'asdased')) V(ID, fID, AnotherString))
SELECT *
FROM T1
     LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T2.AnotherString = 'asd';
```

You *might* expect to get 2 rows here, one for where `T1.ID` is `1` with a joined row and 1 for `T1.ID` is `2`, but with no joined rows. That isn't the case due to the `WHERE`. The correct solution here would be to move the `WHERE` to the `ON`:

```
WITH T1 AS(
    SELECT ID, SomeString
    FROM (VALUES(1,'abc'),(2,'def')) V(ID, SomeString)),
T2 AS(
    SELECT ID, fID, AnotherString
    FROM (VALUES(1,1,'asd'),(2,1,'asdased')) V(ID, fID, AnotherString))
SELECT *
FROM T1
     LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
                 AND T2.AnotherString = 'asd';
```

With what you have, you can't do that, as you're using the base table, thus you'll need handle the `NULL` by changing your `WHERE` to:

```
WHERE SHOWTIMES.ID = 1 OR SHOWTIMES.ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that your database has proper foreign key relationships set up -- so the theater id in one table is a valid id.

If so, you don't need `full join`.  In fact, it is very rarely needed.  I suspect that inner joins are sufficient (but that is the results you are getting).

If you want all theaters with the appropriate shows -- if any -- then use `left join` and start with the theaters:

```
select st.ID AS SHOWTIMESID, st.THEATREID,
       th.THEATRENAME, th.NUMOFROWS, th.NUMOFCOLS,
       s.SEATNO AS SEATLABEL, s.ROWID, s.COLUMNID,
       ti.SEATNO, ti.TICKETCODE
from theatres th left join
     showtimes st
     on st.theatreid = th.id and st.id = 1 left join
     ticket_items ti
     on st.ID =ti.showtimesid left join
     seat s
     on s.seatno = ti.seatno
```

Comment: it should not be "s.seatno = ti.seatno" because "s.seat" are representing all the seats, and "ti.seatno" is only storing tickets that are bought. But i want to display all of them but with an extra column showing "ti.ticketcode" for representing type of sale

Comment: @KIRPALSINGH . . . You should just ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.